# Secure SQL Server for 2 admins

Tags: sql-server

Sorry about the title of the post, but I didn't quite know how to explain this. Here's my issue.

I have a SQL Server that I manage. It is in an Active Directory domain and since I'm the domain admin, I have full rights to it.

I would like to "lock down" the server so that other users can create databases, but cannot have access to mine.

Currently, the other users are using a username that has the same rights as SA. The SA account is scheduled for disabling by the end of the year.

Of course they have become very used to creating there own databases and users without any help from me. I would like to lower there rights so that they can keep using there databases and create any usernames that they would need, but would no longer have the rights of the SA account.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look in Books Online for the topic on server-level roles; you're describing the dbcreator role, which can create & manage their own databases, but not databases created by others.

Comment: Bull. "Members of the dbcreator fixed server role can create, alter, drop, and restore ANY database." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx  A regular user granted the dbcreator role can DELETE ANY database, including databases they do not own, even though they cannot otherwise access them.